# Dame Aylin Missing?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I am in ACT 3 and am trying to complete the sorcerer’s sundries quest with Lorrokan. My issue is that Dame Aylin flew off after she spoke to Shadowheart and gave her the spear. Once I spoke to Lorrokan, everyone told me to go tell Dame Aylin about him… but when I go back to camp she’s not there. I finished Shadowheart’s quest in case that was the trigger, but now I am stuck in limbo because I can’t finish Gale’s companion quest because Dame Aylin is nowhere to be found! Is it a bug? Do I need to start Act 3 over again? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

From what [Reddit says](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/15knepj/cant_find_dame_after_finishing_act_2_boss/)

You might need to start the Act over again, or go to Moonrise Towers, or just kill

> Lorroakan

[Or](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/15knepj/cant_find_dame_after_finishing_act_2_boss/k3g6i1g/) go to "lorroakans tower" and:

> I ended up talking to that short haired merc outside of lorroakans tower and told him that dame aylin was in my camp and he can try to take her. When I long rested, him and his goons came to my camp too try to take her.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of Act 2, after you've finished

> the Ketheric Thorm arc and left the Mindflayer Colony,

you can talk to Dame Aylin and Isobel inside the throne room and invite them to your camp. However, this is an optional dialogue option that you're not required to do. You probably missed this option.

Note that you haven't broken Gale's questline.

> You can kill Lorrokoan in his tower, then do some jumping downstairs to the lower floor and use a Perception skill check to find a plaque that reads vault. Click the nearby button and you'll end up in Lorrokoan's vault, which is where you can find the tome related to Karsus that you need to find for Gale. Alternatively there's a secondary entrance to that vault through a door on the second floor.